# Symlink all Directories inside one directory to another directory

Tags: symlink, nas

I am using a NAS(synology/xpenology) currently with 1 Drive `/volume1/Drive` is the share.
I have other shares on this Drive `/volume1/Drive/SeriesPC` its a share connected to my drive on my pc.

Now I want to symlink every directory from SeriesPC to the Show folders on `/volume1/Drive/Series`

example:

Inside `/volume1/Drive/Series`

- The 100
- NCIS
- NCIS La
- NCIS New Orleans

and inside `/volume1/Drive/SeriesPC`

- 24
- Alias
- The Blacklist
- Under the Dome

now I want it like this

Inside `/volume1/Drive/Series`

- The 100
- NCIS
- NCIS La
- NCIS New Orleans
- 24 > /volume1/Drive/SeriesPC/24
- Alias > /volume1/Drive/SeriesPC/Alias
- The Blacklist > /volume1/Drive/SeriesPC/The Blacklist
- Under the Dome > /volume1/Drive/SeriesPC/Under the Dome

This without needing to create 24/Alias/The Blacklist/Under the Dome directories manually

So every directory inside SeriesPC must get symlinked to Series

I hope I am here right and explained it good enough

Comment: note: I tried ln -s /volume1/Drive/SeriesPC/* /volume1/Drive/Series but it creates files that cant be accessed I also used the "find" comment I found here aswell but it said unsupportive operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the following if you want all the files/directories under SeriesPC to be linked:

```
cd /volume1/Drive/SeriesPC
for i in * ; do ln -s "$PWD/$i" /volume1/Drive/Series/ ; done
```

If not everything under `SeriesPC` should be linked make sure you can `find` just the directories that you need e.g. using  `find * -maxdepth 1 -type d` and then do:

```
cd /volume1/Drive/SeriesPC
find * -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec ln -s $PWD/{} /volume1/Drive/Series/ \;
```

Comment: It doesn't recognize the -t option. Not certain its because of the busybox version or something else? it only gives as option -s/f/n/b/S

Comment: @db3 you can also do `ln -s $PWD/24 /volume1/Drive/Series/`

Comment: Thnxs that works. Guess the only way to do it is to manually enter every directory unless -t gets working somehow

Comment: You can replace the explicit reference to 24 with $i as in my answer, just change the `-t /volume1/Drive/Series/ {}` to `"$PWD/{} /volume1/Drive/Series/"`

Comment: @db3 I updated the answer, it should now be cut and paste, without using the `-t` option for `ln`

Comment: Oke, thnxs it works. Only one more question when trying to access it it says unaccesible or permission denied. I try to access the share from Windows while the permissions are right. I even changed the credentials to that of the admin to connect to the share

Comment: Windows probably cannot follow the the soft links, maybe the network software can map that. Is this mounted via SMB/CIFS on the NAS box?

Comment: Yes its mounted with the CIFS protocol on the NAS

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
cd /volume1/Drive/Series
ln -s ../SeriesPC/* .
```

Comment: Thnxs. Tryed something like that before but withouth the .  Works aswell ty:)